# Why Car wheels rotating weirdly and falling off the car in unity? Updated question

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, game-physics

I am implementing a car controller in unity and it is giving me headache. There are two problems:

1. Front wheels gets rotated 90 degrees in z-axis in play mode.

[image: Before play]
[image: In play mode]

2. Wheels just fall off the car.
   [image: In scene view]
   [image: wheels going down In play mode]

Here is the hierarchy of the car model:
[image: Car Hierarchy]

Searched on google & youtube but did not find anything relevant. Modified the code many times but same wrong result. Help me out please. Here is the entire code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
  [SerializeField] WheelCollider leftFront;
  [SerializeField] WheelCollider rightFront;

  public Transform leftFrontWheelTransform;
  public Transform rightFrontWheelTransform;

  public GameObject player;
  public Transform toBeRolled;

  private float maxTurnAngle = 30f;
  private float currentTurnAngle = 30f;
    
  public static float currentSpeed;
  public static float DriveSpeed = 0.0f;
  public static float slowSpeed;
  public float steerAmount = 120f;
  private float steer;

  private float timer = 0f;
  private float SecondCount = 1f; //Delay time


    void Update()
      {
        slowSpeed = DriveSpeed * 0.7f; //slowSpeed = 5(initial) * 0.7 => 3.5 initially.
        currentSpeed = DriveSpeed;  //5
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            currentSpeed = slowSpeed;
        }

        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        player.transform.position += player.transform.forward * (currentSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;

        float _horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        steer += _horizontal * steerAmount * Time.deltaTime;

        float roll = Mathf.Lerp(0, 0, Mathf.Abs(_horizontal)) * -Mathf.Sign(_horizontal);
        float rollSTEAR = Mathf.Lerp(0, 10, Mathf.Abs(_horizontal)) * -Mathf.Sign(_horizontal);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * steer + Vector3.forward * roll);
        toBeRolled.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * rollSTEAR);

        currentTurnAngle = maxTurnAngle * _horizontal;
        leftFront.steerAngle = currentTurnAngle;    
        rightFront.steerAngle = currentTurnAngle;

        UpdateWheel(leftFront , leftFrontWheelTransform);
        UpdateWheel(rightFront , rightFrontWheelTransform);

         if(timer > SecondCount)
         {
             DriveSpeed += 0.00001f;
             //speed up text & sound on screen
             timer = 0f;
         }

     }
    
    void UpdateWheel(WheelCollider col, Transform trans)
    {
      Vector3 position;
      Quaternion rotation;

      col.GetWorldPose(out position, out rotation);

      trans.position = position;
      trans.rotation = rotation;

    }
}
```

**Update: Okay so I did more research and updated the code and everything works now but I am curious if what I did is the optimal way or just a bruteforce:**

updates:

1. changed car hierarchy to this:
   [image: updated car hierarchy]

2. updated code:

   ```
    using JetBrains.Annotations;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;

    public class CarMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public WheelCollider leftFront;
    public WheelCollider rightFront;
    public WheelCollider leftRear;
    public WheelCollider rightRear;

    public Rigidbody car;

    public Transform LF_wheel;
    public Transform RF_wheel;
    public Transform LR_wheel;
    public Transform RR_wheel;

    public float maxTorq;
    public float maxSteerAngle;

    void Start()
    {
        car = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        takeingInput();
        steer();
        updateWheels();
    }

    public void takeingInput()
    {
       float _vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        //leftRear.motorTorque = _vertical * maxTorq;
        //rightRear.motorTorque = _vertical * maxTorq;

   leftRear.motorTorque = Mathf.Clamp(_vertical, -1.0f, 1.0f) * maxTorq;
   rightRear.motorTorque = Mathf.Clamp(_vertical, -1.0f, 1.0f) * maxTorq;
   ```

   }

   ```
    public void steer()
    {
        float _horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        leftFront.steerAngle = Mathf.Clamp(_horizontal, -1.0f, 1.0f) * maxSteerAngle;
        rightFront.steerAngle = Mathf.Clamp(_horizontal, -1.0f, 1.0f) * maxSteerAngle;

        LF_wheel.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,leftFront.steerAngle,90);
        RF_wheel.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,rightFront.steerAngle,90);
    }
    public void updateWheels()
    {
        wheelUpdate(leftFront, LF_wheel);
        wheelUpdate(rightFront, RF_wheel);
        wheelUpdate(leftRear, LR_wheel);
        wheelUpdate(rightRear, RR_wheel);

        wheelUpdateFix(LR_wheel);
        wheelUpdateFix(RR_wheel);


    }

    public void wheelUpdate(WheelCollider col, Transform trans)
    {
        Vector3 pos; Quaternion rot;

        col.GetWorldPose(out pos, out rot);

        trans.position = pos;
        //trans.rotation = rot;


    }
    public void wheelUpdateFix(Transform trans)
    {
        Quaternion _fixeRot = transform.rotation;
        _fixeRot = _fixeRot * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -90);
        trans.rotation = _fixeRot;

    }
   ```

   }

Comment: Do you have this problem without the script attached?

Comment: The problem occurs with script attached.

Answer (score 0):

A wheel in Unity should be designed as the following structure:

```
Car
 ├ LF collider
 │  └ LF transform (Mesh Filter & Mesh Renderer)
 ├ RF collider
 │  └ RF transform
 ├ LR collider
 │  └ LR transform
 └ LR collider
    └ RR transform
```

Don't move or rotate the object that has a WheelCollider, move or rotate the child node for visual effect.

If the axle isn't along the X axis, you need an addtional transform to constantly rotate the wheel.

```
Car
 └ LF collider
    └ LF transform
      └ Wheel (Put rotated model here)
```

Comment: So, I changed my code and structure and movement works fine but wheel mesh still gives the issue. Tried your solution but that created more mess. now my car structure looks like this: 
Car
 >LF transform
 >RF transform
 >LR transform
 >RR transform
 >LF collider
 >RF collider
 >LR collider
 >RR collider
transforms and colliders are separated. This is the code:

    public void wheelUpdate(WheelCollider col, Transform trans)
    {
        Vector3 pos; Quaternion rot;
        col.GetWorldPose(out pos, out rot);
        trans.position = pos;
        trans.rotation = rot;
    }

Comment: Sorry I can't image the structure from the text, can you add an picture to the question? Based on it, I updated the answer to show how the structure will be.

Comment: I updated the question for more details

Comment: It's a bruteforce. Because your wheels are created using Unity's builtin cylinders, if you use a 3D modeling software to create a wheel, the axle should follow the x axis, so you don't have to rotate it by 90 degrees, if not you can use an additional transform to convert the direction, check my update.